# Edit Personal translation data on form

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, translation

I have set the personal traslation table with this [article](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/translatable.md)

I have a table 'AttrSchool' which has column named 'description' to be translated into three language en,ja,th.

and translated text are stored in AttrSchoolTranslation

Now I made the form to edit and update the 'AttrSchool' data.

```
public function editAttrSchoolAction(Request $request,$schoolId){

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $repository = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:AttrSchool');
    $attrSchool = $repository->findOneBy(array('id' => $schoolId));


    foreach ($attrSchool->getTranslations() as $trans){
        if($trans->getLocale() == 'ja'){
            $desc_ja = $trans->getContent();
        }
        if($trans->getLocale() == 'th'){
            $desc_th =  $trans->getContent();
        }
    }

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($attrSchool)
    ->add('description','textarea',array('required'=> false,'attr' => array('rows' => '8','cols' => '60')))
    ->add('description_th','textarea',array('required'=> false,'data'=> $desc_th,'mapped' => false,'attr' => array('rows' => '8','cols' => '60')))
    ->add('description_ja','textarea',array('required'=> false,'data'=> $desc_ja,'mapped' => false,'attr' => array('rows' => '8','cols' => '60')))

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {

        $attrSchool->setDescription($form->get('description_en')->getData());
        $attrSchool->addTranslation(new \Acme\UserBundle\Entity\AttrSchoolTranslation('ja','description',$form->get('description_ja')->getData()));
        $attrSchool->addTranslation(new \Acme\UserBundle\Entity\AttrSchoolTranslation('th','description',$form->get('description_th')->getData()));
```

However it looks very clumsy.
and it inserts the new AttrSchoolTranslation column, not update.
(That's of course because I called
    new \Acme\UserBundle\Entity\AttrSchoolTranslation.....)

however I don't know how to update the data in the translation table.

Does any one know the hint??

Answer (score 0):

**Persisting multiple translations**

> Usually it is more convenient to persist more translations when
>   creating or updating a record. Translatable allows to do that through
>   translation repository. All additional translations will be tracked by
>   listener and when the flush will be executed, it will update or
>   persist all additional translations.
>
> Note: these translations will not be processed as ordinary fields of
>   your object, in case if you translate a slug additional translation
>   will not know how to generate the slug, so the value as an additional
>   translation should be processed when creating it.

**Example of multiple translations:**

```
<?php
// persisting multiple translations, assume default locale is EN
$repository = $em->getRepository('Gedmo\\Translatable\\Entity\\Translation');
// it works for ODM also
$article = new Article;
$article->setTitle('My article en');
$article->setContent('content en');

$repository->translate($article, 'title', 'de', 'my article de')
    ->translate($article, 'content', 'de', 'content de')
    ->translate($article, 'title', 'ru', 'my article ru')
    ->translate($article, 'content', 'ru', 'content ru')
;

$em->persist($article);
$em->flush();

// updating same article also having one new translation

$repo
    ->translate($article, 'title', 'lt', 'title lt')
    ->translate($article, 'content', 'lt', 'content lt')
    ->translate($article, 'title', 'ru', 'title ru change')
    ->translate($article, 'content', 'ru', 'content ru change')
    ->translate($article, 'title', 'en', 'title en (default locale) update')
    ->translate($article, 'content', 'en', 'content en (default locale) update')
;
$em->flush();
```

Did you tried to call the `translate` method of this `$repository` ?

```
$repository = $em->getRepository('Gedmo\\Translatable\\Entity\\Translation');
```